# Why are there two different pronunciations for the word Tee?

Tags: pronunciation

I found in the German dictionary that the word Tee has two pronunciations.

It sounds [te:] for the drink and [ti:] for the tool used for American football or golf.

I think the former is the standard pronunciation which aligns with the spell.

Comment: The are quite a few other words, which are pronounced differently despite being written the same, the linguists have the term *homographs* for them. See [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Homographe) for more examples.

Comment: ...and this effect is not limited to German: Microsoft recently announced that they would phase out their "resume assistant" in Word, which left me wondering whether this assistant would (a) help people resume [ɹɪˈzjuːm] their work or (b) write a resume [ˈɹɛz.ə.meɪ]. Obviously, the latter is a loan word from French.

Comment: It's worth noting, though, that (at least) Americans pronounce those two "tee"s _**exactly**_ the same, in all dialects/regions I'm aware of. Despite us spelling one as "tea"! @Heinzi: Only a problem because someone was too lazy to write résumé.

Comment: These words are *homographs.*

Comment: Why are there two different pronunciations for the English word *tear*? (*"I have a **tear** in my eye"* but *"I **tear** my shirt.") There are much more examples: *"The servants **bow** to the king" - "With **bow** and arrow"* or *"The **wind** is blowing" - "I **wind** my watch."* or *"Yesterday I **read** a book and tomorrow I will **read** another."*

Answer (score 33):

Those are simply two different words. They are [homographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph).

"der Tee" refers to the tea plant and the beverage.

"das Tee" is a very recent loanword from English and refers to the golf/football device. Consequently, (approximate) English pronounciation is used as for other loanwords from English (e.g., E-mail).

Never forget checking the article (i.e., grammatical gender) when looking up (or learning) German nouns. But even with the same article, it could be two different words.

Comment: Even the phenomenon of differentiating identically spelled words by pronounciation is not unique: der Band/die Band/das Band, das Collagen/die Collagen.

Comment: @JannPoppinga Yes, there are more examples of homographs and it is quite common that they involve loanwords.

Answer (score 11):

German has a tendency to pronounce loan words in (roughly) the same way as they are pronounced in their language of origin.

*der Tee* ("the tea") is coming into German [probably from Dutch *thee*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Tee) and is pronounced alike. *das Tee* ("the tee") comes into German from the American English word and is pronounced alike.

Your hypothesis that the pronounciation  [te:] is "aligning with the spell" is correct.

Comment: As an aside "(der) Tee" was written "Thee" before the 1901 ("Orthographische Konferenz") orthography reform.

Comment: [The etymology of tee is Scottish Gaelic, it is not originally an American English word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee).

Comment: @ToivoSäwén Thanks for the hint! I updated my answer in order to avoid a false impression.